How to remove prepended symbol in entire column from header row using tabularray?
My goal
I wanted to make a document with some bookkeeping tables. I figured having automatic summing etc. would be nice, so I resorted to the use of the spreadtab package. For colored rows etc. I needed tabularray and for formatting of the numbers inside the table I needed the siunitx package.
Question
I added >{€~} to the new column type so I don't have to add the euro symbol myself for every cell. How can I remove the euro symbol in the first row?
MWE
\documentclass{article}

% Unrelated packages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

% Related packages
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage{tabularray}
    \UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

% Setup of how numbers should be displayed
\sisetup{
    output-decimal-marker = {,},
    group-separator = {.},
    group-minimum-digits = 4,
    detect-weight = true,
    round-mode = places,
    round-precision = 2,
    round-pad = true,
}

% Define command to display an amount
\newcommand{\EUR}[1]{%
    €~\num{#1}%
}

% Define column type E to use in tables
% E[<width>]{<spacing>}
\NewColumnType{E}[2][1]{
    >{€~}       % insert euro symbol before cell's element
    X[#1,       % column type that allows relative column widths
        r,      % always right horizontal alignment
        si = {  % use of siunitx library
            table-format = #2.2,            % spacing before and after decimal delimiter
            table-number-alignment = right, % horizontal alignment w.r.t. table
            table-space-text-pre = {€~}     % make sure euro symbol is not part of spacing
        }
    ]
}

\begin{document}

\section{Example}

\NewTblrEnviron{mytable}
\SetTblrInner[mytable]{
    row{1} = {
        guard,
        l, % left-align entire row
        font = \rmfamily\bfseries, % bold face
        bg = azure7, % blue background
        fg = white, % white foreground
    },
    row{Z} = {
        font = \rmfamily\bfseries % bold face
    }
}

\begin{center}
\begin{spreadtab}{{mytable}{
    width = 0.5\linewidth,
    colspec = {
        X[3]
        E[2]{1}
    },
}}
@ Items & @ Subtotal \\
@ Item 1 & 2 + 1/3 \\
@ Item 2 & 3 + 1/3 \\\hline
@ Total & sum(b2:b3) tag(total)
\end{spreadtab}
\STmakegtag{total}
\end{center}

The table shows \EUR{\STtag{total}} as the total.

\end{document}



Instead of removing the symbol from the header, I would only add it to the cells where it is needed:
\documentclass{article}

% Unrelated packages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

% Related packages
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage{tabularray}
    \UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

% Setup of how numbers should be displayed
\sisetup{
    output-decimal-marker = {,},
    group-separator = {.},
    group-minimum-digits = 4,
    detect-weight = true,
    round-mode = places,
    round-precision = 2,
    round-pad = true,
}

% Define command to display an amount
\newcommand{\EUR}[1]{%
    €~\num{#1}%
}

% Define column type E to use in tables
% E[<width>]{<spacing>}
\NewColumnType{E}[2][1]{
%    >{€~}       % insert euro symbol before cell's element
    X[#1,       % column type that allows relative column widths
        r,      % always right horizontal alignment
        si = {  % use of siunitx library
            table-format = #2.2,            % spacing before and after decimal delimiter
            table-number-alignment = right, % horizontal alignment w.r.t. table
            table-space-text-pre = {€~}     % make sure euro symbol is not part of spacing
        }
    ]
}

\begin{document}

\section{Example}

\NewTblrEnviron{mytable}
\SetTblrInner[mytable]{
    row{1} = {
        guard,
        l, % left-align entire row
        font = \rmfamily\bfseries, % bold face
        bg = azure7, % blue background
        fg = white, % white foreground
    },
    row{Z} = {
        font = \rmfamily\bfseries % bold face
    },
    cell{2-Z}{2}={preto={€~}}
}

\begin{center}
\begin{spreadtab}{{mytable}{
    width = 0.5\linewidth,
    colspec = {
        X[3]
        E[2]{1}
    },
}}
@ Items & @ Subtotal \\
@ Item 1 & 2 + 1/3 \\
@ Item 2 & 3 + 1/3 \\\hline
@ Total & sum(b2:b3) tag(total)
\end{spreadtab}
\STmakegtag{total}
\end{center}

The table shows \EUR{\STtag{total}} as the total.

\end{document}



I like how this solution is in the "opposite" direction of where I was looking. However, this means that I'd have to specify where to add the symbol in every column from now on, while I planned that it'd only be relevant to the new E-type columns. I'd hoped it would just be something to add to the E-column definition and that's it. Still, this is not too bad, and it is "customizable". If nothing else pops up, I'll accept this.
